# Is it possible to call a LWC from Apex?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, scheduled-apex, pdf

I need to create a PDF document completely customizable and I decided to use an external JS PDF generation lib (PDF-lib) to create the documents from a LWC **instead of using the Visualforce PDF method**. It works as expected HOWEVER

I would like to Schedule the execution of this PDF creation using Apex, which means calling the LWC somehow from an Apex class.

Has anyone ever achieved that, or is it something that cannot be done in Salesforce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't execute JavaScript from Apex (at least, not without [Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/overview)). If you're trying to render a PDF on-demand, and it's not standard PDF rendering engine, you'll need to callout to another server. You could, for example, use PDFLib on Heroku to generate your PDF files, assuming they fit in the asynchronous limits (12MB of callout per transaction), or you could even have that third-party server use API calls to create the files in Salesforce (e.g. as a ContentDocument).

Comment: Yea that could be an answer to this problem, I did an integration like that with Heroku in the past, but I think it is past the scope of this specific project. Thank you very much for your answer anyways!

Comment: I'm just coming back now to re-accept this answer and thank you for giving me the hint for Salesforce Functions! I worked with Salesforce for some years now and never heard about that until now. It opens so many doors with these types of integrations and projects, I'm amazed with this functionality.

Comment: Don't get your hopes up too much @LuisFernandoKumruyan. Salesforce wanna retire it at 2025 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/salesforce-functions-retirement

Comment: I did, and it didn't go too well... Testing with Functions is not as straightforward as I thought... Even AWS has free tiers for lambda functions.. why doesn't Salesforce have such a thing for Functions?...

Comment: @LuisFernandoKumruyan To be fair, Functions are going away in 2025. Maybe we'll see a better solution in the future. For now, an inexpensive way to deal with this would be to just use AWS or Heroku. The hobby tier is inexpensive enough for light loads.